# Definite integration questions

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate the following :

$ \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ { sec }^{ 2 } } \frac { \pi x }{ 4 } \quad dx $

Comment: What's the derivative of $\tan$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $u = \frac{\pi x}{4}$, $du = \frac{\pi}{4}dx$, and think of the derivative of $\tan$.

Comment: I was intrigued by this problem. so if $int d/dx tan(u)$ then you get $tan(pi\ /4 x)$ from 1 to 0 and then voila 1?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan(x)=\sec^2(x)$